# for loop ++ for something other than 1 in c

Tags: for-loop

suppose I want to use the following for loop in c:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i+3)
    {
    }
```

It wont let me. It will however let me do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    }
```

How do I increase the index by 3 instead of just 1?

Comment: What compiler are you using? That code compiles fine for me using `gcc -std=c99`. Are you using `strict`?

Answer (score 4):

The increment/decrement expression, if used, needs to assign to `i`, not just generate a value.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i+=3)
{}
```

Comment: The C99 standard does not state that it must assign to `i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i=i+3){

}
```

Comment: Or `for(int i=0; i<10; i+=3)`